# Is there anything Like as WMI for Windows same for Linux

Tags: c#

We would like to develop an test tool to work on Linux os systems Is there anything like WMI for linux to establish remotely connectons and execute commands ,get system infos.

Regards,
M.Channabasappa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard is called WBEM.  WMI is just Microsoft's proprietary pseudo-WBEM implementation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-Based_Enterprise_Management

For Linux, google turns up this WBEM option:
http://openwbem.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Channabasappa: They're completely unrelated technologies.  NUnit will "work with" anything that can run a process on a system with a .NET like environment installed (e.g. Mono).  I don't know of any existing plugins for NUnit that will allow it to talk to WMI/WBem, or any existing WMI/WBem providers that expose NUnit as a service.  They may exist, but I've never used them, or bothered to google for them.  You might have to write that layer yourself.

Comment: @Morgan: Already we have created a layer that will work NUnit with WMI,where we will Add the DLL's like WSmanAutomation,system.Management ,which inturn point to WMI,as you said we should create a layer and work on that thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Chann: Glad to help how I can :)  If your code is already interfacing with WMI succesfully, then it probably won't be hard to convert.  WMI is similar to WBEM, from what I've heard, even if it is proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

The CIM support on Linux speaks the standard CIM-XML protocol defined by DMTF (standards DSP0200, DSP0201).

The WMI server support on Windows does not support the standard CIM-XML protocol, and I don't think that the WMI client you integrated into your test environment speaks both the WMI protocol (basically CIM over COM) and the standard CIM-XML protocol.

So what you need is a CIM/WBEM client that speaks the standard CIM-XML protocol and that you can integrate into your test environment.

If the preferred integration method is command line, you could start with the cimcli client from the OpenPegasus project, but then you have to parse its output.

If you need more sophistication, then depending on what programming environments you can deal with in that test environment, you could use the PyWBEM client for Python, or the SFCC client for C language.

Andy